# How to add several token providers in Asp Net Core Identity?

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

In current implementation of my web app I’ve custom class for PasswordResetTokenProvider inherited from DataProtectorTokenProvider with custom options class inherited from DataProtectionTokenProviderOptions. I made this so I can change token lifespan duration.

Also I've a user invitation feature, which allows existing user to invite somebody via email (it creates identity user in db with long meaningless password and send email with password reset link).
Because it uses reset password token - it uses reset password token lifespan duration (30min).

But I want to change lifespan duration  for user invite (1-2 days) and keep lifespan duration for password reset. How do I do this?

As far as I understand – Identity only allows to configure 1 token provider for reset and 1 for email confirm.

[Code in Startup.cs](https://gist.github.com/SuddenGunter/5e2d127ec814998a35f32da2f67a5c61)

Comment: This question has severe formatting or content problems. This question is unlikely to be salvageable through editing, and might need to be removed.

Comment: Noo, I need the answer for this.  What do I need to edit?

Comment: You can add several token providers with `AddTokenProvider<T>("Invite")` in Startup. When you issue user invite use `UserManager.GenerateUserTokenAsync(user, "Invite", "friend")`